# Why can't i resize my main HDD partition even after booting from a USB stick media?

Tags: partition, dual-boot, bootable

[image]I am trying to run windows alongside my POP!_OS and when trying to divide my hdd in half, i find that it's fully used and has no free space when i'm using 1T HDD and i'm more than sure i don't even have 100GB in used storage from there.

I have my partitions unmounted but the option to resize my main one (923GB) is lit up but unclickable, and even when i try to resize using the slider i can't because it's full. What do i do from here?
terribly sorry about the image, i was on the bootable.

Comment: You are using Logical Volumes. Gparted does not know about them and thus can't shrink or resize such partitions

Answer (score 1):

You can't resize LVM Physical Volumes (as mentioned by @rubaiat in a comment). there's 2 ways to solve this:

1. Backup your data, reinstall Linux and take care when formatting to only use half the disk space, restore your data; At your level (no offence) I recommend this option;
2. (this is a complex and lengthy procedure, made worse because of the encryption [which I am ignoring at this point], but it's something that LVM allows)

   - Use a 2nd disk. Create a PV on it and expand your volume group (VG) into the 2nd disk;
   - Move your logical volumes (LVs) to the 2nd disk's PV;
   - Shrink the VG to remove the 1st disk's PV and remove the 1st disk's PV;
   - Repartition the 1st disk taking care not to use more than half the space for the PV;
   - expand your VG to include the 1st disk's PV, move the LVs back to the 1st disk, shrink the VG to remove the 2nd disk's PV, delete 2nd disk's PV;